# Update the PostgreSQL Database every hour via python script or using django models?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, model

I am setting a web server based on Django Framework with PostgreSQL. I need to update the models in my Django app every hour and I am wondering if is it better way to update the database from another script file using python and psycopg2 or using script that directly connects to Django models and update them using Django API for models? I use this Database only in Django web server.

Summarizing... What is better logic?

1. update_db.py that contains:

   - connect to database via psycopg2, update the tables
2. update_db.py that contains:

   - connect to Django app models, update them using Django API for models

I will run script every hour using Cron, and the Django Project is already connected to that specific database and it works fine. I am just asking for better performance and better way in logic sense. Data won't be updated very often but it would have big jsons.

Comment: you can be more pythonic if you use celery perioidic task http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html number 2 is better as they are handling connection pools and disconnect

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari using a complex and costly system when a simple, well-known and stable one exists is definitly not pythonic.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I learnt something thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have very compelling reasons to do otherwise, the obvious solution here is to [use a custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) and the ORM - your code will be at the obvious place (for someone else having to work on the project), can be tested as part of your whole project's test suite, and won't require having to mentally "translate" from raw SQL to Django ORM code (not to mention that you'll have more chance to catch a mismatch between your Django models and your script's code when your schema changes - from experience, raw sql scripts that aren't under test are usually forgotten when doing a schema migration).

FWIW, optimizing "for performances" doesn't really makes sense in your case, unless your updates are long and complex and do block access to the site - but even then the overhead of the ORM is certainly not going to be the main bottleneck (just make sure you use properly).